# How to modify camera settings of shared camera capture in Windows?

Tags: wpf, windows, camera, directx, video-capture

I want to modify the camera exposure while previewing the video capture from my webcam, while I am in a video meeting with Google Meet, Zoom, etc. I'm using the [MediaCapture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.capture.mediacapture) class in a WPF application.

The application works - I can preview the video stream and modify the camera exposure - but only if I initialize the MediaCapture object with [SharingMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.capture.mediacaptureinitializationsettings.sharingmode) set to ExclusiveControl, which prevents other applications (like Google Meet) from accessing the camrea at the same time. If I set the SharingMode to SharedReadOnly then I can run my application at the same time as Google Meet, but I can no longer control the exposure.

I know what I want is technically possible - [OBS Studio](https://obsproject.com/) is able to modify the camera exposure while Google Meet is running - but I don't know if it's possible via the MediaCapture API.

Is there a way to access a shared capture stream AND modify camera settings like exposure? I would prefer a WPF MediaCapture solution, since that's what I'm already using, but I'm open to using another API. Can I do what I want with a lower-level Windows SDK or via DirectX? Thanks for any tips!

Comment: What code exactly do you use to change exposure? Also are you sure OBS is not tweaking the image in software, not the camera settings? OBS is open source.

Comment: My WPF app is setting exposure via `MediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.Exposure`. OBS is definitely changing the camera exposure, because it affects other programs using the camera, like Google Meet. A cursory glace at OBS source code indicates it's using DirectX, so perhaps that's the route I should pursue.